# Integrating Wordpress with my website

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to create a website that allow users to bring/integrate their wordpress account into their account in my website. So, they can manage their blog from my website. Is it possible?

I already have a website running with users, but I don't want to create a blogging system. That's why I'm thinking if wordpress will help.

Comment: Do you have access to WordPress's database?

Comment: I don't have wordpress in my website yet

Comment: Hey @alex, now I have access to the wordpress's database :) what's next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As of WordPress 3.0, you have the ability to create a network of sites (Multisite). This article is instructions for creating a network. It is very similar to creating your own personal version of wordpress.com. -- [codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

Perhaps?

Comment: Will try this out. It sounds like what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Dude, I sort of installed the network and wordpress on my site. All the features are exactly what I wanted. Now I'm confused because I already have a website with users login and registration. This network sort of like a completely new website. How can I integrate them?

Comment: No idea. Maybe you can import/export them somehow? Or perhaps switch to using WordPress login in your other system? Never used it before, so don't really know :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you would want to make use of the WordPress API in your website:

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_API%27s

HTH

Comment: I think I need both, the API and also the Network. I figured out how to use the Network. Now I have problem integrating it with my current site. Things I want such as when users are logged in to my site, they are automatically logged in to wordpress as well. Will the API help? thanks

Comment: I am fairly certain that it will.  I have not worked with the APIs myself, unfortunately, but you will see that the link actually points you to a collection of APIs.  You might want to look at the Database API, as I think sessions are logged whenever a user logs into WordPress.  Good luck!

Comment: Browsed through the API, no luck yet. The API is for developing the Wordpress itself. thanks for the comment anyway :)